# pypyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text')

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, console

i dont understand!

al types are the same with the columns in the database.
im pulling my hair out i dont know whats wrong and this code structure works on 10 other and different files.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TreeCap\PycharmProjects\db_conn\done\AACB Daily Transactions.py", line 483, in 
mycursor.execute(sql_rowcheck, values_rowcheck)
File "C:\Users\TreeCap\PycharmProjects\db_conn\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1480, in execute
self.prepare(query_string)
File "C:\Users\TreeCap\PycharmProjects\db_conn\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1258, in prepare
raise sys.exc_info()[1]
File "C:\Users\TreeCap\PycharmProjects\db_conn\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1252, in prepare
check_success(self, ret)
File "C:\Users\TreeCap\PycharmProjects\db_conn\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
File "C:\Users\TreeCap\PycharmProjects\db_conn\venv\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 977, in ctrl_err
raise DataError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text')

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from main import folder, mycursor, split, question, Color
from datetime import datetime
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Key om te filteren naar welke type file we zoeken
key = "Daily TRXs"




# Hier in komen de bestanden die we vinden met de key woord
gevonden_bestanden = []

# Het rijnummer van de log
rijnummer = 0
huidige_datum = datetime.now().date()
#
# # Hier open we de log bestand
# try:
# log = fr"C:\Users\TreeCap\TreeCap Dropbox\Teammap van TreeCap\1. TreeCap\2. Trading\1. Reconciliation\1. Clearing Output\5. AACB\CSV\log\accountLevellog-{huidige_datum}.log"
# except:

#
#
#
# logging.basicConfig(filename=log,  level=logging.DEBUG,
#                     format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:?')









# Hier halen we alles uit de rowcheck. Daar staan alle bestands namenmaar een keer in.
nameCheck = "SELECT fileName FROM TreeCap.dbo.rowcheck"
mycursor.execute(nameCheck)

# hier zetten we alles in results
result = mycursor.fetchall()
mycursor.commit()

#hier geven we name elke item op als array
name = [item for item in result]


dates = []

#

# file = "20231031-3182-C3182-CSV Daily Cash Summary Account Level-114125229.csv"
# file = split(file, 13, 9, 154, 35, reverse=True)
# print(file)




# Hier lopen we door de mappen en alles heen om alle files te zoeken die overeen komn met de keyword
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    print("looping")
    # Hier word de file1 de eerste bestand in de map
    for file1 in files:
        # Hier kijken we of file1 overeen komt met de keyword en worden die later in deze loop toegevoegd aan gevonden_bestanden
        if key in file1:
            path = os.path.join(root, file1)
            data = pd.read_csv(path)
            data.where(pd.notnull(data), None)

            bestandsnaam = os.path.basename(split(path, 130, 11, 157, 31, reverse=True, single=False))
            print("We hebben dit bestand: ", bestandsnaam, " gevonden.")

            # In de database hebben we de ingekorte namen en hier korten we de namen van de bestands locatie ook zodat we kunnen kijken of ze overeen komen zodat we die kunnen overslaan
            if bestandsnaam not in [item[0] for item in name]:
                # print(name)
                # We zetten alle namen die nog niet in de database zitten in gevonden_bestanden
                gevonden_bestanden.append(path)

                tijd = os.path.getmtime(path)
                tjid = time.ctime(tijd)
                dates.append(tjid)
                # print(tjid)
                # logging.info("Dit is een vastgezet bericht.")

                # print(path)







# In deze loop lezen we de gevonden_bestanden uit en voegen we de naam datum en rows mee aan de database om het in row check te zetten
for item in gevonden_bestanden:
    data = pd.read_csv(item)
    data.where(pd.notnull(data), None)
    expected_rows = len(data)
    # print(item)
    # print(question(36))
    naam = split(item, 133, 8, 157, 31, reverse=True, single=False)
    print(naam, "Word nu toegevoegd aan de database TreeCap")
    print(item)
    # exit()

    sql = f"""
    INSERT INTO TreeCap.dbo.dailytrx (
        date,
        client,
        clientName,
        accountType,
        account,
        accountName,
        subAccount, 
        subAccountName,
        tradeDate,
        transRef, 
        exchange, 
        transactionCurrency, 
        symbol, 
        description, 
        strikePrice,
        expiryDates, 
        ISIN, 
        ULVisin,
        productGroup, 
        putCall, 
        transactionType, 
        movementType,
        openClose, 
        buySell, 
        quanitityLong, 
        quantityShort, 
        tradePrice, 
        grossConsideration,
        grossConsiderationCurrency, 
        externalFees, 
        externalFeesCurrency, 
        clearingFees,
        clearingFeesCurrency, 
        externalMemberId, 
        externalAccount,
        counterParty,
        clientCurrency, 
        conversionRate, 
        tradingUnit, 
        SettlementDate, 
        valuationPrice,
        valuationPriceCurrency, 
        valuationDate, 
        giveupBroker, 
        giveupTakeup, 
        promptDate,
        firstNoticeDate, 
        lastNoticeDate, 
        firstDeliveryDate, 
        lastDeliveryDate,
        contractYearMonth, 
        strategyCode, 
        contractsize, 
        exchangeReference1, 
        exchangeReference2,
        exchangeReference3, 
        relatedTransactionDate, 
        relatedReferenceNumber,
        relatedTransactionType, 
        spotRefPrice, 
        settlementPrice, 
        spotReferenceSettlement,
        expiryMarketSettlement,
        UnitOfMeasurement, 
        tradeTime, 
        matchingTimestampAdditional,
        externalTradeId,
        exchangeTradeID, 
        externalNumber, 
        orderNumber,
        ticketNumber,
        traderInitials, 
        commend, 
        safeKeeping, 
        placeOfSafekeepingId, 
        couponInterestValue,
        couponInterestValueCur, 
        PricingUnit, 
        finalSettlementDate, 
        MICCode, 
        contractualSettlementDate,
        counterpartyBroker, 
        poolRef, 
        settlementInstructionReference

     
    )
    VALUES ({question(84)})
"""

    # sql = list(tuple(row) for row in data_table.head(10).values)


    # Hier loopts hij door alle info verbonden aan de eerste header kopjes aka columns

    # for index, row in data.iterrows():
    #     print(f"Row {index + 1}:")
    #     for header, value in zip(data.columns, row):
    #         print(f"{header}: {type(value)}")
    #     exit()

    for index, row in data.iterrows():



        if 'Report Date' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['Report Date']), "%Y%m%d").date()
        elif 'Date' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['Date']), "%Y%m%d").date()
        elif 'Processing Date' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['Processing Date']), "%Y%m%d").date()
        elif 'ProcessingDate' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['ProcessingDate']), "%Y%m%d").date()
        else:
            print(f"Datum is leeg en de mag niet controleer het bestand {item}")
            exit()


        values = (
            int(row['Processing Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Processing Date']) else None,
            int(row['Client']) if not pd.isna(row['Client']) else None,
            str(row['Client Name']) if not pd.isna(row['Client Name']) else None,
            str(row['Account Type']) if not pd.isna(row['Account Type']) else None,
            int(row['Account']) if not pd.isna(row['Account']) else None,
            str(row['Account Name']) if not pd.isna(row['Account Name']) else None,
            int(row['Sub-account']) if not pd.isna(row['Sub-account']) else None,
            str(row['Sub-account Name']) if not pd.isna(row['Sub-account Name']) else None,
            int(row['Trade Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Trade Date']) else None,
            int(row['Trans Ref']) if not pd.isna(row['Trans Ref']) else None,
            str(row['Exchange']) if not pd.isna(row['Exchange']) else None,
            str(row['Transaction Currency']) if not pd.isna(row['Transaction Currency']) else None,
            str(row['Symbol']) if not pd.isna(row['Symbol']) else None,
            str(row['Description']) if not pd.isna(row['Description']) else None,
            float(row['Strike Price']) if not pd.isna(row['Strike Price']) else None,
            float(row['Expiry Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Expiry Date']) else None,
            str(row['ISIN']) if not pd.isna(row['ISIN']) else None,
            str(row['ULV ISIN']) if not pd.isna(row['ULV ISIN']) else None,
            str(row['Product Group']) if not pd.isna(row['Product Group']) else None,
            str(row['Put Call']) if not pd.isna(row['Put Call']) else None,
            str(row['Transaction Type']) if not pd.isna(row['Transaction Type']) else None,
            str(row['Movement Type']) if not pd.isna(row['Movement Type']) else None,
            str(row['Open Close']) if not pd.isna(row['Open Close']) else None,
            str(row['Buy Sell']) if not pd.isna(row['Buy Sell']) else None,
            float(row['Quantity Long']) if not pd.isna(row['Quantity Long']) else None,
            float(row['Quantity Short']) if not pd.isna(row['Quantity Short']) else None,
            float(row['Trade Price']) if not pd.isna(row['Trade Price']) else None,
            float(row['Gross Consideration']) if not pd.isna(row['Gross Consideration']) else None,
            str(row['Gross Consideration Currency']) if not pd.isna(row['Gross Consideration Currency']) else None,
            float(row['External Fees']) if not pd.isna(row['External Fees']) else None,
            str(row['External Fees Currency']) if not pd.isna(row['External Fees Currency']) else None,
            float(row['Clearing Fees']) if not pd.isna(row['Clearing Fees']) else None,
            str(row['Clearing Fees Currency']) if not pd.isna(row['Clearing Fees Currency']) else None,
            float(row['External Member Id']) if not pd.isna(row['External Member Id']) else None,
            str(row['External Account']) if not pd.isna(row['External Account']) else None,
            str(row['Counter Party']) if not pd.isna(row['Counter Party']) else None,
            str(row['Client Currency']) if not pd.isna(row['Client Currency']) else None,
            float(row['Conversion Rate']) if not pd.isna(row['Conversion Rate']) else None,
            float(row['Trading Unit']) if not pd.isna(row['Trading Unit']) else None,
            float(row['Settlement Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Settlement Date']) else None,
            float(row['Valuation Price']) if not pd.isna(row['Valuation Price']) else None,
            str(row['Valuation Price Currency']) if not pd.isna(row['Valuation Price Currency']) else None,
            int(row['Valuation Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Valuation Date']) else None,
            float(row['Giveup Broker']) if not pd.isna(row['Giveup Broker']) else None,
            str(row['Giveup Takeup']) if not pd.isna(row['Giveup Takeup']) else None,
            float(row['Prompt Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Prompt Date']) else None,
            float(row['First Notice Date']) if not pd.isna(row['First Notice Date']) else None,
            float(row['Last Notice Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Last Notice Date']) else None,
            float(row['First Delivery Date']) if not pd.isna(row['First Delivery Date']) else None,
            float(row['Last Delivery Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Last Delivery Date']) else None,
            float(row['Contract Year Month']) if not pd.isna(row['Contract Year Month']) else None,
            float(row['Strategy Code']) if not pd.isna(row['Strategy Code']) else None,
            int(row['Contract Size']) if not pd.isna(row['Contract Size']) else None,
            str(row['ExchangeReference1']) if not pd.isna(row['ExchangeReference1']) else None,
            str(row['ExchangeReference2']) if not pd.isna(row['ExchangeReference2']) else None,
            float(row['ExchangeReference3']) if not pd.isna(row['ExchangeReference3']) else None,
            float(row['Related Transaction Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Related Transaction Date']) else None,
            float(row['Related Reference Nunber']) if not pd.isna(row['Related Reference Nunber']) else None,
            float(row['Related Transaction Type']) if not pd.isna(row['Related Transaction Type']) else None,
            float(row['Spot Ref Price']) if not pd.isna(row['Spot Ref Price']) else None,
            float(row['Settlement Price']) if not pd.isna(row['Settlement Price']) else None,
            float(row['Spot Reference Settlement']) if not pd.isna(row['Spot Reference Settlement']) else None,
            float(row['Expiry Market Settlement']) if not pd.isna(row['Expiry Market Settlement']) else None,
            float(row['Unit Of Measurement']) if not pd.isna(row['Unit Of Measurement']) else None,
            str(row['Trade Time']) if not pd.isna(row['Trade Time']) else None,
            str(row['Matching Timestamp Additional']) if not pd.isna(row['Matching Timestamp Additional']) else None,
            str(row['External Trade Id']) if not pd.isna(row['External Trade Id']) else None,
            float(row['Exchange Trade ID']) if not pd.isna(row['Exchange Trade ID']) else None,
            int(row['External Number']) if not pd.isna(row['External Number']) else None,
            str(row['OrderNumber']) if not pd.isna(row['OrderNumber']) else None,
            float(row['TicketNumber']) if not pd.isna(row['TicketNumber']) else None,
            str(row['TraderInitials']) if not pd.isna(row['TraderInitials']) else None,
            str(row['Comment']) if not pd.isna(row['Comment']) else None,
            str(row['SafeKeepingId']) if not pd.isna(row['SafeKeepingId']) else None,
            str(row['PlaceofSafekeepingId']) if not pd.isna(row['PlaceofSafekeepingId']) else None,
            float(row['Couponinterest_Value']) if not pd.isna(row['Couponinterest_Value']) else None,
            float(row['Couponinterest_ValueCur']) if not pd.isna(row['Couponinterest_ValueCur']) else None,
            int(row['Pricing Unit']) if not pd.isna(row['Pricing Unit']) else None,
            float(row['Final Settlement Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Final Settlement Date']) else None,
            str(row['MIC Code']) if not pd.isna(row['MIC Code']) else None,
            float(row['Contractual Settlement Date']) if not pd.isna(row['Contractual Settlement Date']) else None,
            float(row['CounterpartyBroker']) if not pd.isna(row['CounterpartyBroker']) else None,
            float(row['PoolRef']) if not pd.isna(row['PoolRef']) else None,
            str(row['SettlementInstructionReference']) if not pd.isna(row['SettlementInstructionReference']) else None

        )
        expected_dtypes = pd.Series({
            'Processing Date': 'int64',
            'Client': 'int64',
            'Client Name': 'object',
            'Account Type': 'object',
            'Account': 'int64',
            'Account Name': 'object',
            'Sub-account': 'int64',
            'Sub-account Name': 'object',
            'Trade Date': 'int64',
            'Trans Ref': 'int64',
            'Exchange': 'object',
            'Transaction Currency': 'object',
            'Symbol': 'object',
            'Description': 'object',
            'Strike Price': 'float64',
            'Expiry Date': 'float64',
            'ISIN': 'object',
            'ULV ISIN': 'object',
            'Product Group': 'object',
            'Put Call': 'object',
            'Transaction Type': 'object',
            'Movement Type': 'object',
            'Open Close': 'object',
            'Buy Sell': 'object',
            'Quantity Long': 'float64',
            'Quantity Short': 'float64',
            'Trade Price': 'float64',
            'Gross Consideration': 'float64',
            'Gross Consideration Currency': 'object',
            'External Fees': 'float64',
            'External Fees Currency': 'object',
            'Clearing Fees': 'float64',
            'Clearing Fees Currency': 'object',
            'External Member Id': 'float64',
            'External Account': 'object',
            'Counter Party': 'object',
            'Client Currency': 'object',
            'Conversion Rate': 'float64',
            'Trading Unit': 'float64',
            'Settlement Date': 'float64',
            'Valuation Price': 'float64',
            'Valuation Price Currency': 'object',
            'Valuation Date': 'int64',
            'Giveup Broker': 'float64',
            'Giveup Takeup': 'object',
            'Prompt Date': 'float64',
            'First Notice Date': 'float64',
            'Last Notice Date': 'float64',
            'First Delivery Date': 'float64',
            'Last Delivery Date': 'float64',
            'Contract Year Month': 'float64',
            'Strategy Code': 'float64',
            'Contract Size': 'int64',
            'ExchangeReference1': 'object',
            'ExchangeReference2': 'object',
            'ExchangeReference3': 'float64',
            'Related Transaction Date': 'float64',
            'Related Reference Nunber': 'float64',
            'Related Transaction Type': 'float64',
            'Spot Ref Price': 'float64',
            'Settlement Price': 'float64',
            'Spot Reference Settlement': 'float64',
            'Expiry Market Settlement': 'float64',
            'Unit Of Measurement': 'float64',
            'Trade Time': 'object',
            'Matching Timestamp Additional': 'object',
            'External Trade Id': 'object',
            'Exchange Trade ID': 'float64',
            'External Number': 'int64',
            'OrderNumber': 'object',
            'TicketNumber': 'float64',
            'TraderInitials': 'object',
            'Comment': 'object',
            'SafeKeepingId': 'object',
            'PlaceofSafekeepingId': 'object',
            'Couponinterest_Value': 'float64',
            'Couponinterest_ValueCur': 'float64',
            'Pricing Unit': 'int64',
            'Final Settlement Date': 'float64',
            'MIC Code': 'object',
            'Contractual Settlement Date': 'float64',
            'CounterpartyBroker': 'float64',
            'PoolRef': 'float64',
            'SettlementInstructionReference': 'object'
        })

        # Zorg ervoor dat de index van expected_dtypes overeenkomt met de kolomnamen van data.dtypes
        diff_dtypes = data.dtypes != expected_dtypes

        # Toon de verschillen in datatypes
        print(f"\nVerschillen in datatypes voor bestand {item}:\n")
        print(diff_dtypes[diff_dtypes].to_string())

        # Controleer of er verschillen zijn
        if diff_dtypes.any():
            # Toon de kolomnamen waar de verschillen in datatypes zijn gevonden
            different_columns = diff_dtypes[diff_dtypes].index
            print(f"\nVerschil in kolomnamen:\n{different_columns}")
            print("\nEr zijn verschillen in datatypes. Het programma wordt gestopt.")
            # Voeg hier andere logica toe of stop de scriptuitvoering zoals je nodig hebt
        else:
            print("Geen verschillen in datatypes. Het programma wordt voortgezet.")
        # print(type(row['Buy Sell']))
        # for key, value in values.items():


        #         print(f"  Column: {column}, Value: {value}")
        # print(f"{Color.OKBLUE}Row: {index + 1}", f"{Color.WARNING}Column: {column}, Value: {value}, Type:{type(value)}")

            # Hier willen we de output aan een log bestand toevoegen en met de regel nummer die we optellen en vergelijken met het aantal in de current csv bestand

    # mycursor.execute(sql, values)
    # mycursor.commit()


    log_print = f"{rijnummer} ~ Succesfully adding: {naam} to Database: Tree Cap\n"
    # print(f"Processing row {index}:")
    # column, value = row.items():
    #         print(f"  Column: {column}, Value: {value}")
    # print(log_print)
    logging.debug(log_print)

    sql_rowcheck = """
                INSERT INTO TreeCap.dbo.rowcheck (
                    date,
                    fileName,
                    expectedRows,
                    givenRows,
                    tableName
                )
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            """











    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        if 'Report Date' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['Report Date']), "%Y%m%d").date()

        elif 'Date' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['Date']), "%Y%m%d").date()

        elif 'Processing Date' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['Processing Date']), "%Y%m%d").date()
        elif 'ProcessingDate' in data.columns:
            datum = datetime.strptime(str(row['ProcessingDate']), "%Y%m%d").date()
        else:
            datum = None

        values_rowcheck = (
            datum,
            naam,
            int(expected_rows),
            int(len(data)),
            'Intrest SubAccount'
        )
    mycursor.execute(sql_rowcheck, values_rowcheck)
    mycursor.commit()

    if rijnummer <= int(expected_rows):
        rijnummer += 1
    elif rijnummer >= int(expected_rows):
        rijnummer = 0








mycursor.close()
```

i keep going up and down checking every data type and if i have a typo somewhere but i cant find nothing chat gpt cant find anything aswell